# Git Forking workflow - integrating feature branch from fork to upstream feature branch

Tags: git, version-control

From the [Atlassian documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow) on the Forking Workflow, you can read:

> Second, they need to notify the project maintainer that they want to merge their feature into the official codebase. Bitbucket provides a “pull request” button that leads to a form asking you to specify which branch you want to merge into the official repository. Typically, you’ll want to integrate your feature branch into the upstream remote’s master branch.

My question is:

Is it overkill to integrate your **feature branch** into the upstream remote's **feature branch**?

Wouldn't this give you a possibility to add another layer of code review? (maybe within a smaller team)

If not, why?

Comment: The purpose of the fork repo is contribute to the orginal git repo while not disturb the main code (official codebase). If you are not intent to contribute to the original git repo, you can also create a new git repo separately, and push the local original repo into the new created repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, it is not overkill: you can integrate your feature branch (through pull request) to *any* branch of the original repo.

You could use an "`integration`" branch as a destination, instead of `master`.

But the main idea remains: *before* pushing your feature branch to your fork, and *before* making that PR to your destination branch ("integration" or any other one), you are supposed to have *rebased* your feature branch on top of the `original_repo/destination_branch`

```
cd /path/to/my/fork/local/clone
git checkout feature
git remote add original /url/original/repo
git fetch original
git rebase original/destination_branch
# check everything is still working
git push --force
# then make your PR
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why we would need to rebase the feature branch on top of the original_repo/destination_branch?

Comment: @forgetaboutme that would be to integrate the latest evolutions of the upstream repo *locally* (in your local repo), by replaying your own feature commits on top of said latest evolutions. Once you have done that, you force push and make your PR. That PR will be trivial to merge: fast-forward, since all its commits are done on top of the upstream branch.